# Get Custom Taxonomy Terms by Date

Tags: customization, taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to get a list of custom taxonomy terms by date (or possibly slug). What I need is the NEWEST term and it's permalink in a custom taxonomy. I've been trying the code below but it's returning the same term over and over again. The goal is to generate a link to the archive page for the newest term in this taxonomy, which happens to be a bunch of journal editions; so a link to the "Latest Edition."

```
// latest edition
$taxonomies = array( 
    'jjm_editions'
);              
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'date', 
    'order'      => 'DSC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'number'     => '3'
);              
$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```

Even if I change ASC to DESC, I always get the first edition.

Edit: I know "number" should be '1'. I have it at three to see what it would output. It still only outputs one term, Edition 6.

Comment: `date` isn't a valid value for `orderby`, taxonomy terms have no date.

Comment: What are the valid orderby for taxonomy terms? Name isn't going to work.

Comment: there isn't a 100% reliable way to do it, the closest you can get [is to do this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71132/4771).

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything either. ASC or DESC returns the same turn. And if I change 'number' to '3' I still only get the one term, the same one every time. Is there something else wrong with my code?

Comment: do the terms have posts associated with them? `hide_empty` set to `true` will only return terms with posts.

Comment: @Milo That was it! Now orderby_id is doing exactly what I want. Thanks! If you'll put that in as an answer I'll give you some thumbs-up love.

Comment: Valid orderby args are here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/class-wp-term-query.php#L99

Answer (score 3):

This is the working code:

```
// latest edition
$taxonomies = array( 
    'jjm_editions'
);              
$args = array(
    'orderby'    => 'ID', 
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'number'     => '1'
);              
$terms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
    if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
}
```